# How to find all the comments written by some user?

Tags: support, comments

Some users have excellent answers and one likes to look for all their answers about any question they replied to. That is easy, but sometimes their answers is in form of comments, or sometimes they give interesting comments.

How to find all the comments written by a certain user?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to their profile, next to "info" you see the "activity" tab.  Example:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/2451/qmechanic?tab=activity

It has edits, answers, questions, and comments as well.

Sorry to pick on you specifically Qmechanic!

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for your help.